# ttyUSB0 works correctly only when echo is set

Tags: linux, serial-port, embedded, tty, u-boot

I have trouble with communication with board using ttyUSB serial.
Everything should go smoothly, just minicom 115200 8N1.
Instead of this I got malformed u-boot init messages

```
~�J���iB
Flash: 32 MiB
In:  ��ɥ��5
Out: ��ɥ��5
Err: ��ɥ��5
Net: �Link: UP
�]���� FULL
Speed L����T    
Q�ɹ�сinit done.
```

I assume its by caused improper tty switch setting.
What is curoius, it starts to work fine after setting **echo** switch (but does a mess on u-boot cli).

My settings are:

```
 stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 cs8 -cstopb -parenb
```

Comment: Either use stty (which will open the port and output to the console) or minicom (which has its own settings in its preferences menu), but not both.

Answer (score 0):

correct string would be stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 cs8 -parenb -cstopb -clocal raw speed 115200 ( according to this web page: http://www.devtal.de/wiki/Benutzer:Rdiez/SerialPortTipsForLinux) since i assume you are not using any modem controls and you have a null modem cable between the device and the PC.
Minicom has to be set first via minicom -s since you have to specify there also the default port speed, parity,etc.